# Add the audio of the original video to the video generated by matlab code

Tags: matlab, audio, video, frame

After running the following code which is trying to generate a new video based on a given video, i lost the original audio in the output video and i want to add this audio to the output, is there any solution for this that i can add it to my code, in other words i want for each frame of the video i want to add the coresponding audio sample.

The code (Just the useful part of the code):

```
while i1 < v1.NumberOfFrames && i2 < v2.NumberOfFrames && i3< v3.NumberOfFrames && i4 < v4.NumberOfFrames
    
    if i1 < v1.NumberOfFrames
        i1 = i1+1;
        im = v1.read(i1);
        im = imresize(im, [290 290]);
        im = imrotate(im,-90);
        iim1 = image(im,'XData',[0 0],'YData',[height1/2 - 290/2 height1/2 - 290/2]);
    end
   if i2 < v2.NumberOfFrames
        i2 = i2+1;
        im = v2.read(i2);
        im = imresize(im, [290 290]);
        im = imrotate(im,180);
        iim2 = image(im,'XData',[width1/2-290/2 width1/2-290/2],'YData',[0 0]);
   end
   
   if i3 < v3.NumberOfFrames
        i3 = i3+1;
        im = v3.read(i1);
        im = imresize(im, [290 290]);
        im = imrotate(im,90);
        iim3 = image(im,'XData',[width1-290 width1-290],'YData',[height1/2 - 290/2 height1/2 - 290/2]);
    end
   if i4 < v4.NumberOfFrames
        i4 = i4+1;
        im = v4.read(i4);
        im = imresize(im, [290 290]);
        iim4 = image(im,'XData',[width1/2-290/2 width1/2-290/2],'YData',[height1 - 290 height1 - 290]);
     
   end
   %frame=im2frame(gcf);
   frame=getframe(gcf);
   writeVideo(writerObj,frame);
    drawnow
```

Comment: What's contained within the structures `v1, v2` etc? You're presently extracting the image only, resize that and then write it to a video file. Of course that doesn't have any sound. That said, I can't find an option within the [documentation on `writeVideo`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.writevideo.html), nor [`VideoWriter`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.html) to add a sound channel to a movie at all.

Comment: I thought it might be a good idea to extract the audio from the original video and then add it separately to my output video, but I am afraid that there will be no synchronization between the audio and the resulted video.